# is there anyway to get nginx to not append the location to the root?

Tags: nginx, location, root

I have an nginx server block that looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /exogeny/ {
        root   /var/www/exogeny/www/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

The idea is, all the different websites have subdirectories under

```
/var/www
```

Each website has its subdirectory where control files like ssl certs etc. go in

```
/var/www/websitename
```

and the files being served for that website go into

```
/var/www/websitename/www
```

in other words, that directory is the root of the files being served.

However, when I do this: curl http://localhost/exogeny/index.html

I get this error in the logs:

```
   /var/www/exogeny/www/exogeny/intro.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

it appended the location to the root. Why? *Why bother having a root directive if it's going to use the location anyway*?

The file is here:

```
ls -l /var/www/exogeny/www/intro.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6028 Aug 22 01:33 /var/www/exogeny/www/intro.html
```

Is there anyway to make it use the root exactly and not append the location? It's a subtle point that people who have not used other web servers might not notice is strange, but it is.

Or am I the asshole here and just configured something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

by default I believe we got on server block enable at var/ww/html directory.
So first make sure single site is works fine in your server.

then if we need additional directories to serve multiple sites.

as you mentioned you can create directory structure for each site inside /var/www
but i prefer the actual web content place inside /var/www/{site domain}/html

such as

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example1.com/html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example2.com/html
```

make sure to assign them to user if your not root user bcz later you dont need to  use 'sudo' to create or update content in these directories.

```
    sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example1.com/html
    sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example2.com/html
    sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Now you can create sample page for each site.

```
    nano /var/www/example1.com/html/index.html
    nano /var/www/example2.com/html/index.html
```

Now lets create server block files. just trying to copy the default file and edit it. Add example for first server1 block as example.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example1.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        
        server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
        
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Now that we have our server block files, we need to enable them. We can do this by creating symbolic links from these files to the sites-enabled directory, which Nginx reads from during startup.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

now you can try restarting nginex.
should work now.
Good luck.